# Hover opacity effects with margins in css and .LESS

Tags: css, hover, less

So basically, I have this little image nav menu with just 4 links.

```
<div class="home_featured_links">
    <a class="hf_link" href="<?=site_url('articles');?>"><img src="<?=site_url('assets/default/images/cta1.png');?>" /></a>
    <a class="hf_link" href="<?=site_url('drills');?>"><img src="<?=site_url('assets/default/images/cta2.png');?>" /></a>
    <a class="hf_link" href="<?=site_url('games');?>"><img src="<?=site_url('assets/default/images/cta3.png');?>" /></a>
    <a class="hf_link" href="<?=site_url('recruiting');?>"><img src="<?=site_url('assets/default/images/cta4.png');?>" /></a>
</div>
```

And what I want to do is have it work so that the images are all at opacity 100(1.0) unless one is hovered over in which case the ones that aren't hovered over switch to opacity 25(.25) so only one image of the 4 will be at full opacity if any of them are hovered over.

Now I've gotten this working, but I am spacing out the 4 image link with a margin-right of 14px and based on the rules I've written so far, if I'm hovering over any of the margins then all 4 of the images will be opacity 25 where as I think it would look better for them all to display at opacity 100 under this circumstance.

I can do this with some jquery or even by adding some filler divs in between but I was wondering if anyone would know a better approach thats pure css/less.

CSS:

```
.home_featured_links {clear:both;float:left;margin-left:22px;margin-top:10px;}
.hf_link {float:left;display:block;width:220px;height:153px;margin-right:14px;}
.home_featured_links:hover .hf_link {.opacity(25);}
.home_featured_links:hover .hf_link:hover {.opacity(100);
```

Comment: Unless I'm overlooking something an extra parent div that's wrapped tightly around the 4 image links seems to be the only way out..

Comment: ah, so an extra rule like .home_featured_link:hover .new_parent:hover .hf_link.....ya let me try that

Comment: ahh that didnt work, or rather I cant conceptualize the proper css rule to write...help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it pure css way, I have a solution for you: (I have tested it)

CSS: (Note that I have removed margin and place it using absolute positioning, since you know the width is 220px)

```
.home_featured_links {clear:both;float:left;margin-left:22px;margin-top:10px;
position: relative;
}
.hf_link {
display:block;width:220px;height:153px;
position: absolute;
}

.hf_link1 {
left: 0px;
}

.hf_link2 {
left: 234px; /* 0px + 220px + 14px */
}

.hf_link3 {
left: 468px; /* 234px + 220px + 14px */
}

.hf_link4 {
left: 702px; /* 468px + 220px + 14px */
}

.home_featured_links:hover .hf_link {.opacity(25);}
.home_featured_links:hover .hf_link:hover {.opacity(100); }
```

HTML: (note that I have added 4 classes)

```
<div class="home_featured_links">
    <a class="hf_link hf_link1" href="<?=site_url('articles');?>"><img src="<?=site_url('assets/default/images/cta1.png');?>" /></a>
    <a class="hf_link hf_link2" href="<?=site_url('drills');?>"><img src="<?=site_url('assets/default/images/cta2.png');?>" /></a>
    <a class="hf_link hf_link3" href="<?=site_url('games');?>"><img src="<?=site_url('assets/default/images/cta3.png');?>" /></a>
    <a class="hf_link hf_link4" href="<?=site_url('recruiting');?>"><img src="<?=site_url('assets/default/images/cta4.png');?>" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: works like a charm.  thanks.  I'd rather avoid the absolute positioning, but i guess theres no choice if i want to do it purely css. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
.home_featured_links {clear:both;float:left;margin-left:22px;margin-top:10px;}
.hf_link {float:left;display:block;width:220px;height:153px;margin-right:14px;}
.home_featured_links:hover .hf_link { opacity: 0.25;}
.home_featured_links:hover .hf_link:hover { opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: no.  .opacity() is a filter provided by .less.....dont have to worry about dumb Microsoft deprecated opacity properties this way.

Comment: I understand. And I spent sometime figuring out how to do that and found a solution. Look at the other answer I have posted. Regards.